# Odoo 10 or above - enhance search

Tags: odoo, inventory

after removing filter_domain , it shows error:

[image]

---

** Updated 1st Feb 2018 **

Here is a code under a path in my ..odoo/addons/ted/models/ted_inventory.py

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class TedInventory(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    trackingnum = fields.Char('trackingnum', readonly=True, index=True, help="Tracking number")  
    custom_name = fields.Char(string='Tracking Number',compute='_compute_custom_name',search='_search_custom_name')

    @api.multi
    @api.depends()
    def _compute_custom_name(self):
       ''' The field has to be a computed field
        You do not need to do anything here
       '''
       pass

    def _search_custom_name(self, operator, value):
        res = []
        if operator == 'ilike':
            query = "SELECT id FROM stock_picking WHERE position(trackingnum in %s) >= 1"
            self._cr.execute(query, (value,))
            res_ids = [x[0] for x in self._cr.fetchall()]
            res.append(('id', 'in', res_ids))
            return res
```

I am sure my app is installed as I can find the custom_name and trackingnum in stock.picking model.

I have also included a new search code in SearchView as:
[image]

When I search like this here, the search result is nothing (as I expect to dig out record of TN1234):

[image]

Comment: What are you tried? please show us some piece of your code.

Comment: I have above codes but it doesn't work and I have no idea of what it is wrong.

Comment: and this code is placed in the related View    <field name="custom_name" string="Tracking Number" filter_domain="[('trackingnum','ilike', self)]" />

Comment: i am thinking of can i make use of an iteration loop with find() to identity records. But I have no idea of how to make the code.

Comment: At first don't add code as picture... SO has syntax highlighting so please add your code as text. At second i don't understand your question: Give a really simple example: What records are existing (with important field content), what is the search phrase and what records should be the outcome after search.

Comment: example:  some records with field trackingnum = "Z123"    search phrase is "xyZ123abc" and i want to take out all the records. you see - search phrase contains a longer string but it embeds "Z123"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator that you are using for is wrong couse ilike search the value into field but you need the other wise, search the field into the value, I got a solution for your problem but I don't think that it is the best approach, but it works:

In SQL: *position(field in str)*, search field into str.

```
def _search_custom_name(self, operator, value):
    res = []
    if operator == 'ilike':
        query = "SELECT id FROM stock_picking WHERE position(trackingnum in %s) >= 1"
        self._cr.execute(query, (value,))
        res_ids = [x[0] for x in self._cr.fetchall()]
        res.append(('id', 'in', res_ids))
        return res
```

You need to consider the others operators too.

I hope this could be helpful for you!

Comment: Hi Juan, just use your code but it doesn't show up the result I want (but no error; just as the original search by short chars). May be I get some wrong with the codes in files. How could I send you codes for simply review?

Comment: Firat edit your question and post your code using the editor, do not paste a picture of your code, and second, use and database manager to show your data and execute the query show in my answer.

Comment: Avoid *filter_domain* attribute, and check again.

Comment: if removing filter_domain.. , there is Odoo error:   .....  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1048, in determine_domain
    return getattr(records, self.search)(operator, value)
AttributeError: 'stock.picking' object has no attribute '_search_custom_name'

Comment: Please show your complete SearchView code(no pic) definition, I checked my code and it works perfectly. Do not forget update your module.

Comment: hi Juan, you are right. I can work out it now. Thanks a lot. Forgive me keeping you a long time wait.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and what was the problem?